# Calling VBA procedure - error missing =

Tags: vba, excel-2007

I tried to call a VBA procedure named Ins_to_temp but it doesn't work. Strange, as Ins_to_temp is built from the model of another procedure: Truncate_table that DOES work!

Can you please help me understand why this gives an error on line "Ins_to_temp(x,y,z)" - it says an "=" is missing! (as if it was a function but it's obviously a procedure)

```
Sub Ins_to_temp(tbl1 As String, tbl2 As String, idx As String)
    Connect
    Dim strQ As String
    Set rstR = New ADODB.Recordset
    rstR.CursorType = adOpenStatic
    strQ = "insert into " & tbl1 & " (select * from " & tbl2 & " where id = '" & idx & "')"
    rstRec.Open strQ, objCon, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
End Sub

Sub Test()
   Ins_to_temp("temp_clients","clients","202")

End Sub
```

For the reference, here is a procedure that DOES work:

```
Sub Truncate_table(tbl1 As String)
    Connect
    Dim strQ As String
    Set rstR = New ADODB.Recordset
    rstR.CursorType = adOpenStatic
    strQ = "DELETE FROM " & tbl1
    rstR.Open strQ, objCon, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
End Sub
```

I can call it as: Truncate_table("coll")
Thank you

Comment: remove the brackets, ie call it as `Ins_to_temp "temp_clients","clients","202"`

Comment: The ´insert into´ can only work, if tbl1 and tbl2 have exactly the same columns in the same order!

Comment: Thank you both, yes, removing the brackets did the trick, I can't believe it, thanks! But isn't it strange that the truncate procedure works with brackets? So I am guessing maybe it's ok to put brackets when you have one argument, but not when you have several due to syntax rules? Amazing.

Comment: see this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478101%28VS.85%29.aspx) for explanation of the impact of `()` on procedure calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what about this, does it work?

```
Sub Test()
   Ins_to_temp tbl1:="temp_clients", tbl2:="clients", idx:="202"
End Sub
```

Comment: Funny, I had tried that initially, but with brackets! I will try this variant too, for sure it will work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a typo :

```
Sub Ins_to_temp(tbl1 As String, tbl2 As String, idx As String)
    Connect
    Dim strQ As String
    Set rstR = New ADODB.Recordset
    rstR.CursorType = adOpenStatic

    strQry = "insert into " & tbl1 & " (select * from " & tbl2 & " where id = '" & idx & "')"

    ' the line above should be

    strQ = "insert into " & tbl1 & " (select * from " & tbl2 & " where id = '" & idx & "')"

    rstRec.Open strQ, objCon, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
End Sub
```

Comment: I made the typo when writing the question here but originally the code doesn't contain it, so it should be something else. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I guess the first thing to check is if the error is from the VBA or from the query. If you type the SQL string manually, do you get an error?

Comment: Thank you roger! - it worked after removing the brackets: Ins_to_temp"temp_clients","clients","202"